# YCOE Old English Corpus

Tags: corpora, old-english

I need some help in figuring out how to use the YCOE Old English Corpus. Specifically, I need to write a query that will allow me find all the occurences of temese ("Thames") as well as find all the occurences of se temese ("The Thames"). So far, I have only managed to write the following query files (which don't work when used with CorpusSearch):

node: NP*

query: (temese)

and,

node: NP*

query: (se precedes temese)

If someone could help me, it would be much appreciated.